# group by operation in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading groupby function in pandas in book Data analysis using python. Here author mentioned as below.

```
In [13]: df = DataFrame({'key1' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
....: 'key2' : ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'],
....: 'data1' : np.random.randn(5),
....: 'data2' : np.random.randn(5)})

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
    data1       data2   key1 key2
0   -0.204708 1.393406  a    one
1   0.478943  0.092908  a    two
2   -0.519439 0.281746  b    one
3   -0.555730 0.769023  b    two
4   1.965781  1.246435  a    one


In [21]: states = np.array(['Ohio', 'California', 'California', 'Ohio', 'Ohio'])
In [22]: years = np.array([2005, 2005, 2006, 2005, 2006])

In [23]: df['data1'].groupby([states, years]).mean()
Out[23]:
California 2005 0.478943
           2006 -0.519439
Ohio       2005 -0.380219
           2006 1.965781
```

My question is how df['data1'] is groupbed as df is no where linked to states and years. I am not geeting how output is produced. Kindly explain

Comment: This is due to the [intrinsic data alignment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#intro-to-data-structures) in Pandas.   Pandas wants to do mostly all operations based on the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

When performing a [**`groupby`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) you can pass

> - **by** : mapping, function, str, or iterable
>
>   - Used to determine the groups for the groupby. If by is a function, it’s called on each value of the object’s index. If a dict or Series is passed, the Series or dict VALUES will be used to determine the groups (the Series’ values are first aligned; see .align() method). If an ndarray is passed, the values are used as-is determine the groups. A str or list of strs may be passed to group by the columns in self

---

**`iterable`**

In this case you passed an iterable or an array.  When you use an array, you had better have the same length as the dataframe itself.  Otherwise:

```
# Doesn't throw an error because the length of `df` is 5
df.groupby(list(range(5)))

# This does throw an error
df.groupby(list(range(6)))

KeyError: 0
```

---

**`pd.Series`**

Consider the series `s` where we specify the length to be the same as `df` as well as the index to be the same.

```
s = pd.Series(list(range(len(df))), df.index)
```

Then when we do a `groupby` the indices are [**`aligned`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html)

```
df.groupby(s)
```

With a `pd.Series` we don't have to be concerned with the length, because, pandas will do the alignment for us

```
# also works
df.groupby(s.append(pd.Series(1, [len(df)])))
```

---

**`str`**
In the case of a string being passed to the `gropuby`, pandas will look for a column with that name to `groupby`.

---

**`function`**
In the case of a function being passed, pandas will map that function on the index of `df` and use the resulting `iterable` to groupby.